# DST Handling In Java 5 For Corner Dates

Tags: java, timezone

According to the following website daylight saving time in UK starts from 27 Mar-2016 1:00:00 (24 hours time format)
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2016
Then why the following code prints false?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class BSTGMTDetector
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        TimeZone def = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");    

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        cal.clear();
        cal.set(2016, 2, 27,2,01,01);

        boolean isInDaylight = def.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Date[" + cal.getTime() + "] is  in DST[" + isInDaylight + "]");    

    }
}


Output : Date[Sun Mar 27 02:01:01 IST 2016] is  in DST[false]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your system maintain IST.When you define,

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

Timezone for **cal** variable is IST.So,when call

```
def.inDaylightTime(cal.getTime());
```

Date is passed to this method in IST timezone.So,DST start for UK at 27th MAR,06:30:00 IST.
Hence.your O/P behaviour.

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat for date time parsing,and keep in mind that calender has month index starting from 0(for Jan)

Comment: USe joda time for better results